# Victory Chart x-axis scale not working for Dates

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, victory-charts

I have an Area chart in Victory where the x-axis has dates.
I want to customize the x-axis Label and have created a CustomLabel component to calculate the x-axis scale and display "LABEL" below the ticks. 
But for some reason, the scale is not calculated correctly for the Date Object.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/3203z3n7r6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may face this issue, I raised the issue in their Github Page and one of the authors has given a fix for it. Please see below:

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/1075